# is it possible to send a bin file over spi interface

Tags: spi, bin, intel-edison

I have an FPGA connected to a mini computer (Edison) over SPI. Is it possible to send a bin file over spi to program the fpga? Does that even make sense? How would one split up a bin file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to send binary over SPI. All data are represented in binary format while working with SPI.Hence you can send binary through SPI.
You can set the bit mode(i.e. no of bits to get transferred in a transactions) and divide your bin size with the bit-mode to get number of transactions.Now, call tx-rx for those many number of transactions.